# How to get the day of the week from a tm object in C++?

Tags: c++, date, datetime, c++11

I'm trying to write a program which parses a string representing a date formatted as YYYYMMDD (using `strptime()`) and prints it in the form of dayOfWeek, Month Day, Year (using `put_time()`). Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    struct tm tm;
    string s("20131224");
    if (strptime(s.c_str(), "%Y%m%e", &tm)) {
        cout << put_time(&tm, "%A, %B %e, %Y") << endl;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the day of the week is always a Sunday, regardless of the date.

It appears to be a problem with `strptime()` not populating the day of the week information if only given a year, month, and day, and then `put_time()` not filling in this information either.

According to [this documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rtref/strpti.htm) for `strftime()`, "missing fields in the tm structure may be filled in by `strftime()` if given enough information." I haven't found the same information regarding `put_time()` (which `strftime()` appears to be based on), so perhaps I'm expecting too much of the function.

**Can `strptime()` automatically fill in the day of the week (`tm_wday`) on input, given a year, month, and day? Or can `put_time()` automatically fill this information on output? If not, is there another way to add this information to a `tm` object?**

Comment: _missing fields in the tm structure **may** be filled_ Use [`std::mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime)

Comment: According to [`strptime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html), there're no requirement to fill the missing fields

Comment: Never would've thought it'd be that simple. Only other thing I had to do was add `struct tm tm = {0};` (to initialize all fields to zero) and `tm.tm_isdst = -1;` (to force DST lookup to prevent errors). Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do it without using the C API, but instead the C++11/14 `<chrono>` facilities and this [free, open-source, header-only library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    istringstream s("20131224");
    date::sys_days tp;
    s >> date::parse("%Y%m%e", tp);
    if (!s.fail())
        cout << date::format("%A, %B %e, %Y", tp) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Tuesday, December 24, 2013
```

`date::sys_days` above is just a `typedef` for a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` but with a precision of `days` instead of whatever your platform provides (microseconds, nanoseconds, whatever).  And that means you can easily add other durations to it, such as std::chrono::hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc.

```
cout << date::format("%A, %B %e, %Y %H:%M", tp + 2h + 35min ) << endl;

Tuesday, December 24, 2013 02:35
```

You can paste the above code into this wandbox demo and try it out for yourself for various versions of clang and gcc:

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PodYB3AwdYNFKbMv

Answer (score 3):

Try this  (compiled in Mac)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const string DAY[]={"Sun","Mon","Tue",
        "Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};

    time_t rawtime;
    tm * timeinfo;
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo=localtime(&rawtime);

    int weekday=timeinfo->tm_wday;
    cout << "Today is: " << DAY[weekday] << "\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```